# Downloading/Loading Images in .NET MAUI CollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, maui

I am trying to load images in a collection view in .NET MAUI but they are not showing.  The images have to be retrieved via URL or from disk, depending if they have been downloaded already.  I am trying to update the image path after the ForecastData object is created in the QueryApi method.  The collectionview loads the text information fine but not the images.  Under every weather description there should be a small 100x100 icon for the weather.

This approach works for page in my application when a single weather object is used but I cannot seem to get it to work in a collection view. An obvious workaround is to include the images at compile time but I would prefer to fetch the icons at runtime

Page

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WeatherApp.Pages.ForecastWeatherPage"
             Title="5-Day Forecast">

    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="20"
                         Spacing="40">

        <Entry Placeholder="ZIP"
               Text="{Binding ZipCode}"
               MaxLength="5"
               WidthRequest="200"
               HeightRequest="40"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" />
        <Label x:Name="CityLabel"
               FontSize="40"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               TextColor="Gray"
               Text="{Binding CityName}" />

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding WeatherForecast}"
                        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VerticalStackLayout    Margin="20"
                                            Spacing="40">
                        <Label x:Name="WeatherDescriptionLabel"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               TextColor="SlateGray"
                               Text="{Binding WeatherDescription}" />
                        <Image Source="{Binding WeatherImagePath}"
                               Aspect="AspectFit"
                               MaximumHeightRequest="100"
                               MaximumWidthRequest="100" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

view model

```
using WeatherApp.Services;
using WeatherApp.Models.ForecastWeatherModel;
using ForecastData = WeatherApp.Models.WeatherDataObject;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using WeatherApp.Pages;

namespace WeatherApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ForecastWeatherViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private string zipCode;
        private string cityName;

        private Root weatherForecastRoot;

        public ObservableCollection<ForecastData> WeatherForecast { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<ForecastData>();
        
        public ForecastWeatherViewModel()
        {
            weatherForecastRoot = new Root();
            zipCode = string.Empty;
            cityName = "Please Enter Zip Code";
        }

        public string ZipCode
        {
            get => zipCode;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref zipCode, value);
                if (zipCode.Length == 5)
                {
                    QueryApi();
                }
            }
        }
        public string CityName
        {
            get => cityName;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref cityName, value);
            }
        }
        private async void QueryApi()
        {
            if (int.TryParse(zipCode, out var convertedZipCode))
            {
                weatherForecastRoot = await ApiService.GetWeatherForecast(convertedZipCode);
                
                if (weatherForecastRoot != null)
                {
                    CityName = weatherForecastRoot.city.name;
                    
                    List<ForecastData> preparationList = new List<ForecastData>();

                    foreach(var weatherReport in weatherForecastRoot.list)
                    {
                        foreach(var report in weatherReport.weather)
                        {
                            ForecastData weatherDataObject = new ForecastData(report.description, report.icon);

                            if (!FileService.isIconDownloaded(weatherDataObject.WeatherIcon))
                            {
                                byte[] imageByteArray = await ApiService.GetWeatherImageFromIconCode(weatherDataObject.WeatherIcon);
                                weatherDataObject.WeatherImagePath = FileService.SaveIconToAppData(imageByteArray, weatherDataObject.WeatherIcon);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                weatherDataObject.WeatherImagePath = FileService.GetIconPath(weatherDataObject.WeatherIcon);
                            }
                            preparationList.Add(weatherDataObject);
                        }
                    }
                    WeatherForecast = new ObservableCollection<ForecastData>(preparationList);
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WeatherForecast));
                }
                else
                {
                    CityName = "Cannot locate city/region by zip code";
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if that is a valid image path I'd expect it to work.  If you put a standalone `Image` control at the bottom of the page and assign it one of the paths, does that work?

Comment: its a valid path and if i replace the binding with something on disk or on a site it appears in the collection view

Comment: are you using OpenWeatherMap?  If not, which API are you using?

Comment: Using the 5 day 3 hour forecast
https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Comment: Why aren’t you just using the url of the image instead of downloading it?

Comment: It does not work for me in maui, i think its to do with how the icon filename is formatted.  "01d.png" violates the image name rule where it has to begin with a lowercase character. I rename the images elsewhere and it works then.

Comment: the naming rules apply to files, not urls.  This works fine for me `<Image Source="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d.png" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting HeightRequest="400" in the collection view revealed the icons.  Lesson
Learned.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding WeatherForecast}"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                HeightRequest="400">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout    Margin="20"
                                    Spacing="40">
                <Label x:Name="WeatherDescriptionLabel"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       TextColor="SlateGray"
                       Text="{Binding WeatherDescription}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding WeatherImagePath}"
                       Aspect="AspectFit"
                       MaximumHeightRequest="200"
                       MaximumWidthRequest="200" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: It is not a correct path.

I am 99.99% sure that for icon you have something like this: "01d"
Instead of something like:`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png`

Second: This is not going to render in release at all.
At this line: `<DataTemplate>` you HAVE TO specify the type you are using.

Third: (this is only recommended) I would have used Width/HeightRequest.

Comment: the icon code is separate from the image path here, FileService returns a path to the image file on disk after it is fetched by ApiService.  It works when using open weathers current weather API without collection view.

I am not following you on the DataTemplate issue.  That is being done in ItemSource and the weather description renders just fine.

Comment: @NotIntelligentException https://stackoverflow.com/a/75285858/6643940