Get element after item click on collectionview via mvvm
I am trying to get the clicked item on my collection view (what a noble idea).
I am happy with the inner workings of my view:
<CollectionView SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ClickCommand}" SelectionMode="Single"  SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding WifiHotSpots}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

I am also happy with having the click being registered inside my command:
[RelayCommand]
public void Click(object obj)
{

}

... however, I am unhappy with my obj not containing anything. It is null.
How can I return the clicked item?
EDIT:
The selected Item (which was just a test I believe):
    private object _selectedItem;
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
            }
        }
    }


where are you setting SelectedItem?

Please show where SelectedItem is defined and how you set it.

I am answering this:

I am trying to get the clicked item on my collection view

First, specifying your Model class in your DataTemplate is mandatory:
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:MyModel">

(Julian pointed out, that it is not mandatory, if you never specified your ViewModel, never skipped it myself, because I do not get binding typo warnings, TODO: test)
Second, I advise you to use tap gesture, let's say I have Grid in the DataTemplate:
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer...

Third, the way you go get to the ViewModel, and execute the command is with:
<TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                      Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType= 
{x:Type viewmodel:MyViewModel}}, Path=MyCommand}"/>

It is the most basic way to get the clicked item.
Edit
When you see "model:MyModel" and "local:MainPage", "viewmodel:MyViewModel", you have to understand that MyModel, MainPage, MyViewModel are classes. And model, local, viewmodel are name spaces.
And let's say we have MainViewModel, that is at the top-level namespace of my application.
To use it for binding, you do this:
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"

And after that you set your view model as DataType:
x:DataType="local:MyViewModel"

The same way you can add your model namespace as XML namespace and use it when setting DataType of the collection. And also the same way, you can specify your view model as type for the command binding. By declaring "viewmodel" name space.
You can pick any words, not just "model", "viewmodel" etc. It is just an example.

Actually, specifying the x:DataType on the DataTemplate is only mandatory, when you also have specified the x:DataType anywhere higher up in the hierarchy of the ContentPage/ContentView up to where the BindingContext is set.

@Julian and what is he doing with "{Binding .}" ? I mean, he is doing some binding. There is set DataType, its not part of the code sample...

If the x:DataType is not specified on the root element or lower down in the hierarchy, the "{Binding .}" will still work. This is only a problem with compiled bindings.

@Julian I do not see everything, but leaving DataTemplates empty, without specifying the DataType is the main cause of empty CollectionViews in Release mode.

But under which conditions? Normally, that only happens when the type cannot be inferred and that's usually the case when there's a mismatch between the compiled binding and the actual type. Now, I'm always in favor of specifying x:DataType wherever possible, because it not only speed up the binding resolution, but it also makes it easier to read and navigate the code and assists tools and IDEs.

@Julian https://stackoverflow.com/a/75285858/6643940 It is edited by you btw...

I know, and what is that supposed to tell me? We cannot see whether the OP of that question has specified the x:DataType anywhere else in the hierarchy, either.

@Julian wait, anywhere? Even at top level ContentPage?

Yes, exactly. I think that's where a lot of the confusion and issues come from. Developers define the x:DataType on the root level of the ContentPage and then forget to specify it down the line, when the binding/data context changes. That's when things start to fall apart.

@Julian this may actually work... I have never skipped the step, to specify what ViewModel I am using.

You could simply update your answer to say "recommended" instead of "mandatory" and then our "discussion" here becomes moot. (Although I'm not sure if your answer will actually solve the issue the OP is having, because we don't know enough about SelectedItem yet).

hello and thank you: how do i catch the click in code? also i dont understand the part with the: viewmodel:MyViewModel - my viewmodel is called "wifipageviewmodel" but i cant just paste it in ther; it says not valid xaml

@innom I have made an edit. You should replace it with : viewmodels:wifipageviewmodel, where viewmodels is the declared xmlns at the top, pointing to the namespace that you have in WifiPageViewModel.cs.

I solved it myself eventually doing this:
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ClickCommand, Source={x:Reference WifiPageViewPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

it takes an x:name on the page for the reference,.

Close enough...
