NetMaui - CollectionView isn't showed on Android
I created a NetMaui Application and in a page I have a collectionview
when I execute the application in windows I don't have problem , but in android the collectionview isn't showed
I have this problem in debug and in release
enter image description here

Could you please show the related code?

Is this only in release? If yes - check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283345/collectionview-working-in-debug-but-not-in-release-in-net-maui/75285858#75285858

I Solved
the issue was that when CollectionView is in a RefreshView in Android the items aren't showed
I put collectionview out RefreshView
before(Error)
<RefreshView ......./>
    <CollectionView ......./>
</RefreshView>

after(solution)
<RefreshView ......./>
<CollectionView ......./>


You can refer to the XAML syntax, if you complete the tag with a forward slash and closing angle bracket in succession (/>), this represents self-closing form that doesn't have any content.
